# Firestore Security rules match array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to retrieve all members that have a particular ID in the array "types".

members in firestore:

```
{
  types: ["userId1", "userId2"]
}
```

security rules:

```
match /members/{types} {
  allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/members/$(types)).data.parents.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);

  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/members/$(types)).data.parents;
}
```

Both get me access denied, help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query that isn't working the way you expect.  We need to be able to see that the query matches the rules.

Comment: db.collection("types").whereField("parents", arrayContains: userId).getDocuments()

Comment: That query won't be matched by the rules you show here.  It's querying a collection called "types", but your rules are defined to work with "members".

Comment: You're right, my bad:
db.collection("members").whereField("parents", arrayContains: userId).getDocuments()